# Convert Json to x-www-form-urlencoded by Postman

Tags: json, postman, x-www-form-urlencoded

I need to know how to Convert The list of object (SERVICES) to x-www-form-urlencoded by Postman

**My Json Inputs :**

```
 {
    "BILLING_NUMBER": "554128536954",
    "EVENT_KEY": " BUNDLE",
    "PROCCESS_DATE": "",
    "LANGUAGE": "EN",
    "VERSION": "1",
    "SERVICES": [
                 {
                   "SERVICE_CODE": "ODB_12345"
                 },
                 {
                   "SERVICE_CODE": "ODB_123445"
                 }
              ]
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution as below:

```
BILLING_NUMBER:554128536954
EVENT_KEY:BUNDLE
PROCCESS_DATE:
LANGUAGE:EN
VERSION:1
SERVICES[0].SERVICE_CODE:ODB_12345
SERVICES[1].SERVICE_CODE:ODB_123445
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it’s a bit stupid, but I did it this way.If the json string is simple style,not nesting,**you can convert ',' to '\n' remove all '"' and '{' and'}', then filter all space if needed**,In Body->x-www-form-urlencoded->**Bulk Edit** input it, it will be the right format to read.
for example,

```
 {
    "BILLING_NUMBER": "554128536954",
    "EVENT_KEY": " BUNDLE",
    "PROCCESS_DATE": "",
    "LANGUAGE": "EN",
    "VERSION": "1",
}
```

to

```
BILLING_NUMBER:554128536954
EVENT_KEY:BUNDLE
PROCCESS_DATE:
LANGUAGE:EN
VERSION:1
```