# Convert JSON Nested Node to x-www-form-urlencoded in Postman

Tags: json, postman, x-www-form-urlencoded

Can someone please let me know how we can convert the below `JSON` to `x-www-form-urlencoded` format using the post. I checked the this link but it didn't work.
[Convert JSON to x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408981/convert-json-to-x-www-form-urlencoded-by-postman)

I didn't find a satisfactory answer for this yet.

```
{
    "Dto":
       6897
    ,
    "ConfirmationResponses":{
        "Tenants_Delete":true
}
}
```

If i use the above `JSON` in raw, it works fine in postman. See below screens please

[image]

but it doesn't work for `x-www-form-urlencoded`. It does not read the Tenants_Delete command.

[image]

Two other ways, i tried are below

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this

[image]

Output ==>  Req==>{"Dto":"689","ConfirmationResponses":{"Tenants_Delete":"true"}}
POST /submit 200 21.842 ms - 7

[image]

Comment: Please Mark best answer

Comment: i already tried this. You can see it in my post. Am i missing something ? All the three ways are included in question